# How can I only replace a specific word in a string using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
 var query =  select id, Details.Id, Details.Info.Id from DetailsItem
```

I want to replace Details with [Details], so I am using

```
query.Replace(" Details", " [Details]");
```

I get the following

```
select id, [Details].Id, [Details].Info.Id from [Details]Item
```

but it replaces DetailsItem which I dont want. How can I only replace if the word is Details only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Regex.Replace()` method with word boundary i.e `\b`,

```
string queryResult = Regex.Replace(query, @"\bDetails\b", "[Details]", RegexOptions.None);
```

[.Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i8Exgn)

Comment: Works if I use `@"\bDetails\b"` (without space before 'D')

Comment: tried it without the \b and it didnt work